# loading java server pages on a lamp server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat7, lamp

How can I load JSP on a lamp server? I have a tomcat7 installed but I dont want to have to load localhost:8080

I have lamp on ubuntu and would like my jsp pages to work on just localhost. Is this an option?

Comment: What do you mean by "you don't want to *load* localhost:8080"?

Comment: Sounds like the work for [Apache mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html)

Comment: LAMP - Linux Apache Mysql PHP(or Python).

Comment: i have tried mod_jk but i get an error 404 Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 with requested resource not available. Only when I got to localhost/context/ (location i set in apache) but i go to localhost:8080 then tomcat is running fine